# Eclipse auto space brackets

Tags: eclipse

I somehow disabled the auto indent when typing {}
I mean

once if I wrote

```
if (c) 
{}
```

and enter a space between the brackets it would automatically do this

```
if (c)
{
    ...
}
```

how to located this option?

Answer (score 1):

Under "Preferences": Java > Editor > Save Actions

1) Check "Additional actions"

2) Click "Configure…"

3) Go to the "Code Style" tab

4) Check "Use blocks in if/while/for/do statements" and configure to your preferences

other places that it might be:

Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit -> Braces.
 The brace position you want is Next line indented

Comment: tried it and its not working, the problem is i need to manually enter the braces make space between and then press tab, and once the eclipse done this automatically.

Comment: @joseRo did you upgranded version?

Comment: no I did some changes (I dont remember what i did) and suddenly it stopped working, although is minor its killing me

Comment: @joseRo i know the feeling, but the only other suggestion i can give you is to to google it a bit more...